# Print array of strings - Shell Script

Tags: arrays, string, loops, shell

Dears,

Simple question, I have a shell variable with the following values,

```
myarr=["Life","is","good","when","you","learning"]
```

It is an array of strings ! Here is how I want to print it. Also, I need to do with a loop because each of these element would be passed to a function to process the string

**Expected Output**

```
Life \
is \
good \
when \
you \
learning
```

Comment: Dear, Simple comment, I would like to see you include in your question what you have tried,

Comment: `myarr=["Li...` this is not how arrays in Bash shell are working.. What shell is it? What shell are you using? `Expected Output` Should the ` \` be part of the output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a for loop to print all the elements of your array.

```sh
# declare your array variable
declare -a myarr=("Life","is","good","when","you","learning")

# get length of an array
length=${#myarr[@]}

for (( j=0; j<${length}; j++ ));
do
  printf "${myarr[$j]}\n"
done
```

Comment: Arrays are separated by whitespace, not by `,` comma. `j<${length};` no need for `$(`, you can just `j < length`

Answer (score -1):

An array literal is declared in the shell like so:

```
myarr=(Life is good when you learning)
```

And if you have such an array you can pass it to `printf` like so (note the `"double quotes"` around the expansion):

```
printf "%s\n" "${myarr[@]}"
Life
is
good
when
you
learning
```

You use `"double quotes"` if you have spaces in individual elements when declaring the array:

```
myarr=("Life is good" when you learning)
printf "%s\n" "${myarr[@]}"
Life is good
when
you
learning
```

You can also just make a string value then NOT use quotes which will split the string:

```
mys="Life is good when you learning"
printf "%s\n" $mys
Life
is
good
when
you
learning
```

Beware though that that will also expand globs:

```
mys="Life is good when * you learning"
printf "%s\n" $mys
Life
is
good
when
...
a bunch of files from the glob in the cwd
...
file
you
learning
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation but the example given by @el-mehdi-yessad seem to be helpful